# Find types that inherit from given INamedTypeSymbol

Tags: c#, roslyn

Given an `INamedTypeSymbol` (that comes from an referenced assembly, not source) how can I find all types (in both **source and referenced assemblies**) that inherit from this type?

In my particular case, I'm looking for all types that inherit from `NUnit.Framework.TestAttribute`. I can get access to the named type symbol as follows:

```
var ws = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
var soln = ws.OpenSolutionAsync(@"C:\Users\...\SampleInheritanceStuff.sln").Result;
var proj = soln.Projects.Single();
var compilation = proj.GetCompilationAsync().Result;

string TEST_ATTRIBUTE_METADATA_NAME = "NUnit.Framework.TestAttribute";
var testAttributeType = compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName(TEST_ATTRIBUTE_METADATA_NAME);

//Now how do I find types that inherit from this type?
```

I've taken a look at `SymbolFinder`, `Compilation` and `INamedTypeSymbol` but I haven't had any luck.

**Edit:** The [`FindDerivedClassesAsync`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Shared/Extensions/INamedTypeSymbolExtensions.cs,913cf9f3a8fdbd8c,references) method looks close to what I need. (I'm not 100% sure that it finds derived classes in referenced assemblies). However it's internal, so I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4900).

Comment: Can you have a reference to the "Assembly" object?

Comment: If you can have the assembly object you could use the method GetTypies and filter using the method IsAssignableFrom

Comment: It's not going to be easy to get the `Assembly` object, and I know it's possible to do with reflection, but I would really prefer to use Roslyn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FindDerivedClassesAsync` is indeed what you are looking for.
It finds derived classes in referenced assemblies, as you can see in the source code for [`DependentTypeFinder`](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/FindSymbols/FindReferences/DependentTypeFinder.cs,9659d3ef82cea8ff,references) (notice the `locationsInMetadata` variable).

As for using it, you can always do it with reflection in the meantime:

```
 private static readonly Lazy<Func<INamedTypeSymbol, Solution, IImmutableSet<Project>, CancellationToken, Task<IEnumerable<INamedTypeSymbol>>>> FindDerivedClassesAsync
            = new Lazy<Func<INamedTypeSymbol, Solution, IImmutableSet<Project>, CancellationToken, Task<IEnumerable<INamedTypeSymbol>>>>(() => (Func<INamedTypeSymbol, Solution, IImmutableSet<Project>, CancellationToken, Task<IEnumerable<INamedTypeSymbol>>>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<INamedTypeSymbol, Solution, IImmutableSet<Project>, CancellationToken, Task<IEnumerable<INamedTypeSymbol>>>), DependentTypeFinder.Value.GetMethod("FindDerivedClassesAsync", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)));
```

([code borrowed from Tunnel Vision Laboratories Github](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/InheritanceMargin/blob/master/Tvl.VisualStudio.InheritanceMargin.CSharp/CSharpInheritanceAnalyzer.cs))

Good luck!

**UPDATE:**

This method has been made public by now. [(source)](https://github.com/jasonmalinowski/roslyn/commit/718d037ec27f271f0447ae0d1dfcba45310f38d7)

Comment: I've given you the bounty (but not the answer) because this is the closest approach I've seen yet. Unfortunately it doesn't look like this API finds derived types in referenced assemblies.

Comment: I tested this today and it seems to find derived types in referenced assemblies as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this information using the SemanticModel exposed from the Compilation

```
public static IEnumerable<INamedTypeSymbol> GetBaseClasses(SemanticModel model, BaseTypeDeclarationSyntax type)
    {
        var classSymbol = model.GetDeclaredSymbol(type);
        var returnValue = new List<INamedTypeSymbol>();
        while (classSymbol.BaseType != null)
        {
            returnValue.Add(classSymbol.BaseType);
            if (classSymbol.Interfaces != null)
            returnValue.AddRange(classSymbol.Interfaces);
            classSymbol = classSymbol.BaseType;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
```

This will give you a list of all the base classes as well as every interface that each base class implements.   You can then filter to the INamedTypeSymbol that you are interested in:

```
        public static IEnumerable<BaseTypeDeclarationSyntax>
              FindClassesDerivedOrImplementedByType(Compilation compilation
        , INamedTypeSymbol target)
    {
        foreach (var tree in compilation.SyntaxTrees)
        {
            var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);

            foreach (var type in tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes()
                        .OfType<TypeDeclarationSyntax>())
            {
                var baseClasses = GetBaseClasses(semanticModel, type);
                if (baseClasses != null)
                    if (baseClasses.Contains(target))
                        yield return type;
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: I believe `baseClasses.Contains()` returns false for types with generic constraints (where derived class has additional constraints).